# Flink: assign watermark to FlinkKafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a FlinkKafkaConsumer defined as follows `FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)` and I'm working with event time by using `setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)`.

Now I want to assign a periodic watermark with the function `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks`, but I don't know what I should pass to that function since in the documentation the example of this function receive an element of type `MyType` with a `getCreationTime()` and my consumer is of type String.

Is it possible to assign event time in this situation?

EDIT: The time I would want to use as event time is the time each register was stored in Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of `EventTime` is at least in the definition strictly connected with the time at which events are created rather than received. So, if the events that You are consuming from Kafka have some kind of timestamp (for example if You are consuming JSON as String and then parsing it) then you can use this timestamp inside the `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` function.

If you are parsing plain `String` objects then the best thing You could do is to use custom `KafkaDeserializationSchema` to extract Kafka timestamp for each event and use this.

Technically, You could even use the counter that increases artificially timestamp for each record(for example by incrementing it by 1), but this doesn't seem to make sense in terms of `EventTime` processing.

Comment: The string I'm consuming is a JSON, but doesn't have any field with a timestamp on it. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Why do You want to use the `EventTime` then ?:)

Comment: It was to use IntervalJoin. I thought that there might be a way to get an event time from Kafka topics, but it's only possible to use it if the data received has a timestamp  implicitly (i.e a field in a json with it). Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Another question: would it be possible to use the storage time (when the data was stored in kafka) as a watermark?

Comment: I believe you can trick Flink into doing an interval join by setting the time characteristic to IngestionTime.

Comment: If You use the `KafkaDeserializationSchema` then on deserialization You have access to the whole record, which means You can also access the timestamp that was assigned by Kafka on the moment that record was written to the topic. You could use that :) It doesn't need to be embedded in the JSON itself.